# Реакция на данные в БД.

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Привет всем, у меня недавно возникла ситуация. Заключается она в том что нужно оправлять письма пользователям, например за 5 дней до их дня рождения.

Example:

```
userName: "Bohdan",
birthDay: 20.04.1997
```

А отправить письмо нужно 16.04.

Как реализовать данный функционал? Или хотя бы как правильно сформулировать вопрос, чтобы скормить его гуглу.

У меня была идея построить механизм, который делает обход целой БД ночью в 00:00.

Но возможно есть более правильный подход к реализации данной функциональности.

Проект базируется на ASP.NET WebAPI + AngularJS

Спасибо всем за ответы.

Comment: я думаю более правильно будет выбирать записи от текущей даты и добавлять до нее 5 дней, и если будут записи то делать обход и посылать уведомление

Comment: *была идея построить механизм* для этих целей можно воспользоваться **Hangfire**. Статейка на хабре - https://habrahabr.ru/post/280732/

Comment: `var date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(5);
var users = Context.Users.Where(u => u.BirthDate.Day == date.Day && u.BirthDate.Month == date.Month);
foreach(var user in users)
    MyPostman.SendMail(user);`

Comment: Спасибо большое за советы.